# Ovirt shutdown solution for large number of VMs

Tags: python, ansible, ovirt

I am looking for swift ovirt shutdown procedure/project, which involves large number of active VMs. I found an open pull request at github for parallel shutdown i.e. https://github.com/oVirt/ovirt-ansible-shutdown-env/pulls. I wonder if there are other or better solutions.

I am trying to develop or find a working solution which works with NMS like libreNMS to receive alerts and based on power failure alert, perform swift ovirt shutdown including hosted engine, vms etc...

Does a solution like this already exist as this should be quite common for handling power outages.

Answer (score 0):

Currently i use [ovirtclt](https://github.com/danykey/ovirtctl) for autostart selected vm. So you can use it for shutdown.

```
Usage:
vm-list
vm-start|vm-stop|vm-shutdown|vm-reboot|vm-suspend|vm-get <vmName>
vm-start-all|vm-stop-all|vm-shutdown-all
```